# align div center in front of other divs with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to align div with loader in front of other divs at center of the page.

Could someone please show me working example how to accomplish it with jquery?

Comment: We'll need to see the HTML and styles of the elements you want to manipulate, and what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I need to show div with loader in front of others divs during callback, and then hide it

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this should work:

```
$('.element').css({ position: 'absolute', top: '50%', left: '50%', marginTop: -$('.element').outerHeight(), marginLeft: -$('.element').outerWidth(), zIndex: 1000})
```